# PHP Video Upload Not Working

Tags: php, video

I have a PHP video upload script, where it only accepts .mp4 files. The PHP version is 7. Here is my form (Simplified):

```
<form method="post" action="something.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="video">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Here is the PHP (Simplified):

```
$video = $_FILES["video"];
var_dump($video);
```

Assume that the file selected to upload was a video, it was a mp4, and it was about 2 to 3 minutes. Also assume that we check that the submit button was actually clicked.

Here is the output of the PHP:

```
array (size=5)
  'name' => string 'Sample Video.mp4' (length=16)
  'type' => string '' (length=0)
  'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
  'error' => int 1
  'size' => int 0
```

I have multiple sample video files, all ended up in the same error. Why is PHP unable to get the file? Normally I would expect that the `tmp_name` should have a file which I can read through php.

> Edit: I am using PHP 7, and this is on localhost for a mac osx high sierra.

Comment: are there any error message?

Comment: @Charis, I didn't get any error messages.

Comment: No warning at all? Could it be the script cannot write to tmp folder?

Comment: Maybe, but shouldn't that give a warning / error? How would I go about fixing that?

Comment: yes. It should show a warning unless the warning error is surpressed and just written to log. What php version did you use?

Comment: PHP 7. But errors normally do show in a table which has a yellow/gold header. I think it might be useful to know that this is running on localhost on a mac version high sierra.

Comment: Okay, kind of weird. I use the same setup. php installed with homebrew. While locahost setup wont affected by max_file_size and execution time in my experience. Did you use MAMP or nginx as web server? Could you try using `php -S localhost:8080` to serve the public folder. It could be web server related problem.

Comment: I used XAMPP, I just have to put this in the terminal right: `php -S localhost:8080`.

Comment: So I ran the command, but how do I change the document root of the webserver, normally in localhost the document root is `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`. How do I change the document root of the command?

Comment: use -t parameter. You could read this. http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Web Server setup. I shifted my code from `localhost` to an actual domain. That solved the issue for me. After that, my php upload code worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

i think you need make a steatment condition t check if that file uploaded or not

```
<?php
  $target_dir = "uploads/";
  $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
  $uploadOk = 1;
  $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
  // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
       $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
       if($check !== false) {
           echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
   } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
         $uploadOk = 0;
   }
} ?>
```

so you know if the file uploaded or not

get that code from [W3Cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Comment: The question clearly states "Video Upload". And if you see the code that you just posted, you used echo to show that the file in not an image if the user doesn't click the submit button. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: The code that you posted will crash in my case because of this line: `$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);`. You are calling getimagesize with an empty string.